# Checking whether a label exists between two other labels in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I have a column (call it A) in Excel lists off different items and their properties.  Every item has the word "Type" associated with it and so there is a cell with that label in column A so that in the column beside it (B) the type can be listed.  Some (not all) items also have a "Widget" label associated with them.

Since each item only has one "Type" label I would like to be able to do is have Excel search for the "Type" label and then check whether there is a "Widget" label BEFORE the next "Type" label, and if there is paste the value in column B adjacent to the "Type" label in another sheet.  It would continue doing this until no more instances of the word "Type" were found.  Is this something that's feasible to implement?  To make the layout more clear a sample column is below.  Note that the number of spaces between each entry, unfortunately, is not consistent and so cannot be used as a way to track where one is.  Similarly, the word Widget does not have to be directly above Type, it can appear anywhere between the two instances of "Type" that bookend it.

```
**Type**  01
Width     .5
Length    .4
Height    .3
Weight    15
Widget    Blue
**Type**  072
Width      .1 
Length     .1
Height     .1
Weight     50
**Type**   025
Width      .4
Length     .4
Widget     Red
Weight     11
Height     .4
```

The desired output on the separate sheet would then simply be:

```
01
025
```

since those are the types that have a widget associated.

Comment: I'm concerned that your sample data has been redacted too far. Is `**Type**` literally repeated several times as a category delimiter or has that label been homogenized from different *types* in the actual data? If the latter, what uniquely distinguishes each *type* from the other entries?

Comment: So the objective is for the output table to show **Type** 01 Blue in three contiguous columns?  (Apparently, the asterisks around Type cause it to show bold in the comments.)

Comment: @fixer1234: You know that `**text**` is Markdown for **`text`**, don't you? You can get `**Type**` with backticks, or \*\*Type\*\* by typing a backslash before each `*`.

Comment: @G-Man - Thanks.  I knew about the markdown.  Wasn't aware that you can defeat it with backticks or backslashes.

Comment: Trying again: So the objective is for the output table to show `**Type**` 01 Blue in three contiguous columns?

Comment: The purpose of the site is to compile questions and answers for future reference and people get their problems solved in the process of doing that.  Your question is ambiguous as to what you want the result to look like, and each person who answered interpreted it differently.  The question and answers won't be much help to future visitors.  Could you edit your question and add an example of what the output should look like?  That would enable others to understand the question and answers.

Comment: @fixer1234 Hi fixer, I saw your other comment and provided sample output.  I should have thought about how the question could be interpreted beforehand - really I was just looking for a single list of types for which a widget of any kind is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated formula.  Finds the cell with the first type and second type and looks for the word widget between it.  If it exists return the value beside type if not return blank.

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("widget",INDIRECT("A" & SMALL(IF(A:A="type",ROW(A:A),1000000),E1) & ":A" &                
SMALL(IF(A:A="type",ROW(A:A),1000000),E1+1)),0)>0,INDIRECT("B" & 
SMALL(IF(A:A="type",ROW(A:A),1000000),E1)),""),"")
```

Entered with ctrl+shift+enter

Cell E1 would have the number 1, E2 would have number 2.  Copy the formula down to return each instance of WIDGET.  Will error if there isn't anymore so you could use an iferror around it.

Would probably take a while to calculate (or my comp is just slow due to doing other things right now). and you may be better off using a macro.

Below is a very quick attempt.  It lists them from the bottom up.  Basically it cycles from the last row to the first.  If it finds widget it turns a flag on.  If the flag is on and it finds a type it returns the cell next to it.

*Edited the macro to work with finding type or widget in the string and not just an exact match

```
Sub get_types()

Dim lRow As Long, cRow As Long, nRow As Long
Dim FindType As Boolean

FindType = False
nRow = 2

With Sheets("sheet1")
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For cRow = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(UCase(.Range("A" & cRow).Value), "WIDGET") > 0 Then FindType = True
        If FindType And InStr(UCase(.Range("A" & cRow).Value), "TYPE") > 0 Then
            .Range("E" & nRow).Value = .Range("B" & cRow).Value
            FindType = False
            nRow = nRow + 1
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Output, blue cells should get listed, red cell gets skipped because it doesn't have a widget.  Cells listed in reverse order due to direction of the loop.

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly this will return each entry in column B associated with "widget" and not the entry in column B associated with the "Type" associated with "widget".

Comment: Sorry I read the question wrong.  I'll post an answer but it will take forever if the data set is fairly big.  It will also leave blank rows if there are types that have no widgets

Comment: Both of those things are definitely manageable, thanks so much.  I'll take a look at the macro now.  EDIT:  The one thing I'm wondering is how can I write the function $ISNUMBER(SEARCH("WIDGET",A1,0)))$ in VBA?  Sometimes there might be hidden characters as the data is quite messy.

Comment: added a commented out line but you are looking for instr("Find text here", "text") which will return 0 if not found.

Comment: Thanks so much.  One final question:  An error on "Then" in your commented code results in an error "Compile Error, expected list separator."  Any idea what might be causing this.  I'm looking into it as I write this.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion in this thread about what the desired output is supposed to look like.  Your answer satisfied the OP but for future visitors, it isn't obvious what your output looks like.  Could you edit your answer and just add a mockup of a sample result?

Comment: Added a comment for the output from the macro.

Comment: @gtwebb So the code seems to run fine now, but no output appears in the specified output column.  I know that's vague, but I thought I might ask if you had any ideas on how to resolve the issue.

Comment: It works fine using you data above.  Copy the table into A1 split it into columns (split based on space), and run macro.  If you have been copying the data from here I would guess that it wasn't split into columns but I can't really trouble shot anymore then that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an IF AND statement like:

```
=IF(AND(A1="Widget",A2="**Type**"),B2,"")
```

That basically tells Excel IF the text "Widget" is in a cell above a cell with the text "**Type**", enter the data from the cell in column B next to "**Type**", otherwise, leave it blank.

You end up with this:

[image]

If you want the data (072 in this example) to show up in another sheet, then your formula needs to refer to the cells in their specific sheet instead. Assuming you have the data on a worksheet called "Sheet 1", use this formula on the worksheet where you want the data to appear:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!A2="Widget",Sheet1!A3="**Type**"),Sheet1!B3,"")
```

Comment: Unfortunately the data I am dealing with is slightly messier than that.  For example, Widget may not be directly above **Type**, it is just somewhere between the two instances of **Type**.  Because of this it isn't possible to track using A1,A2 as you have done.  I should have made this more clear, sorry.

Comment: Maybe you can help clarify by showing what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: The issue with your formula isn't really the output, which is great, it's more that it relies on "Widget" and "Type" being a fixed width apart from each other.  This assumption cannot be made with the data I have unfortunately.

Comment: @MaxPower - is the value in C6 above supposed to be **072** or **01**?

Comment: @MaxPower It should be 01, but that's secondary to the issue of being able to check above or below for the "Type" associated with the "Widget" in the first place I think.  I should have been more clear on that though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on your sample data and requirements. Note that I have expanded your sample data to demonstrate how multiple scenarios are dealt with.

[image: Widget Types]

The standard formulas in D2:G2 are,

D2 is =IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"Widget")>COUNTIF(D$1:D1,"Widget"),"Widget","")
`

E2 is `=IF(LEN($D2),INDEX($B$1:$B$9999,SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$9999)+($A$1:$A$9999<>"widget")*1E+99,,),ROW(1:1))),"")`

F2 is `=IF(LEN($D2),INDEX($B$1:$B$9999,SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$9999)+($A$1:$A$9999<>"**Type**")*1E+99,,),COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A1:A"&SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$9999)+($A$1:$A$9999<>"widget")*1E+99,,),ROW(1:1))),"**Type**"))),"")`

G2 is `=IF(LEN($D2),VLOOKUP("**Type**", INDIRECT("A"&SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$9999)+($A$1:$A$9999<>"widget")*1E+99,,),ROW(1:1))&":B9999"), 2, FALSE),"")`

I've cut down the referenced cell ranges from full column references in order to minimize calculation lag. Both `INDIRECT` and `INDEX` (in its array form here) are considered *volatile* functions that recalculate whenever a calculation cycle occurs; not just when a value changes that directly affects them. Fill down as necessary.

I have made that sample workbook available for you on my OneDrive [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=161352CE07628E22!3431&authkey=!ACbEhZAvYrUm2c8&ithint=file%2cxlsx) to reference and download.

[Widget_types.xlsx](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=161352CE07628E22!3431&authkey=!ACbEhZAvYrUm2c8&ithint=file%2cxlsx)

That will likely keep you occupied for a bit while transcribing the formulas for your own purposes. Post back with any *specific* questions that you have if you run into a problem.